# With coverage.py, how to skip coverage of import and def statements

Tags: python, coverage.py

I have a python program that imports other files which potentially import other files, as is normal with python development

The problem is, when I measure coverage with coverage.py, some files which are imported but not used, get coverage "hits" on the def and import statements.

My question is: is there are way to avoid those hits? For my particular application these hits are considered noise.

Comment: Why are you importing files that aren't used?

Comment: @jwodder this is a very big system and which I have no control of. my assignment is is to write a application which show coverage of the system in a smart way

Comment: Then perhaps you should leave coverage.py's results alone so that the coverage hits from the unused imports come to the attention of someone who can fix the imports.  That's what the coverage report is for, right?

Comment: @jwodder its not that simple. my assignment is to provide the best tools that I can for other people to use at their own schedule.

Comment: Coverage.py has no idea why lines were run, only that they ran.  I recommend that you not worry about the lines that are run by importing files that aren't used.  They add to the total, but the difference between 75% and 77% is meaningless anyway, except that 77 is more than 75.  Why is it so important to ignore lines run by files that are imported but not used?

Comment: At the end, it's kinda easy to game the results if you code in a way that most of the lines are covered by just importing the file. A code review could get those cheating techniques, but it could be useful to be able to ignore all those imports or definitions on the coverage report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since coverage.py does not provide this feature, my solution was to write a small ast based function that calculate ghost hit points and remove them from the the coverage.py results

Edit (after 5 years), here is the relevant code:

```
import ast
def calc_ghost_hits(text):
    def calc_args(node):        
        args=node.args
        if args:
            args=args.args
        if args:
            for arg in args:
                yield arg.lineno    
    def calc_decorators(node):
        for x in calc_args(node): yield x
        for decorator in node.decorator_list:
            yield decorator.lineno
        returns=node.returns
        if returns:
            yield returns.lineno
        
    def calc_it(branch,level):
        for x in ast.iter_child_nodes(branch):
            lineno=x.lineno
            if lineno is not None:
                yield lineno           
            t=type(x).__name__
            if t=='ClassDef' and level==0:
                for x in calc_it(x,level+1):
                    yield x
            if t=='FunctionDef' and level<=1:
                for x in calc_decorators(x):
                    yield x
    return list(set(calc_it(ast.parse(text),0)))
```

Comment: Awesome. @yigal can you share it?

Comment: Hi @yigal , I'm looking for similar solution , can you share your function

Comment: @yigal - Would you be able to share the code for your solution. Thanks.

Comment: edit: I just added the requested code

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `exclude_lines` configuration, as per documentation https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.2/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion.

For example (quoting from the link pasted above):

`[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    def __repr__
    if self.debug:
    if settings.DEBUG
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError
    if 0:
    if __name__ == .__main__.:`

Answer (score 1):

Coverage.py has controls for what files to include, and which to omit: http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1/source.html  You can tailor which files it will measure.

Comment: yes I know that. but that does not solves my problem as it  removes files based on names. I want to remove individual hits based on the hit nature.

Comment: I don't know what "hit nature" means.